# Does AWS Glue have ability to poll document db records and write to a file in bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-documentdb

I have couple of use cases and just wondering if AWS glue can solve it or not. First use case is we receive data from upstream system via SQS and save them to DocumentDB on AWS. Our requirement is to poll records received for that specific day from documentdb with certain status, enrich data with more information by pulling from another data source, generate file and then upload to s3 so that another team can consume it. Second requirement is different files will be uploaded to s3 bucket per day and we need to read the file, parse it and then update data in 2 different data sources. Can AWS Glue help solve both the requirements? Or is there a easy way to do it. Appreciate any help or suggestions.